# QGIS - Installation issue Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: qgis, installation, windows-7

I am currently trying to install QGIS but it has been on the same point of the installation for almost 30 minutes. I don't know if it is simply taking a long time to create a folder, but it seems as though there is an error in the installation process. It appears as if it's in the "finishing" process, but there's a bug.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well the installation seemed to have simply ran into an error allowing the installation window to change to the "Finish" screen. I had to end process (end task did nothing) and reinstall. Thankfully, the .exe file immediately gave the me option to reinstall. If you run into this bug, ensure that you end process and reinstall with the .exe file that you downloaded from the QGIS site.

Comment: This is from the native Windows installer, isn't it? As a further alternative, you could try out the OSGeo4W version, which has many additional GIS utilities like GDAL, proj, GRASSGIS and many more. Because in the end you usually need more than QGIS ;) Check it out [here](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/)